# Consequences of habitual overconsumption of water?

Tags: water, hydration, sodium, water-retention

I know the consequences of drinking too little water (dehydration then death), and drinking too much water within a period of time (also death), but what are the consequences of consistently drinking slightly too much water?

I'm curious about the long-term health consequences of consistently having 1-3L of unneeded extra water per day (so for example, if I need X litres per day to be healthy, but I have X+1L or X+3L per day consistently). Aside from additional urination there's no obvious short-term symptoms but there may be a long term impact on health which I'm oblivious to.

Comment: Mind to tell what benefits of extra water do you expect? Beside possible (not firmly proven) decreased risk of kidney stones--mainly in those with personal or family history of kidney stones--there are no known benefits of drinking extra water, as far as I know. Also, I am not aware of any physical harm of drinking "X+3" liters of water per day except of constant visits to the toilet (if I find a link, I'll answer below).

Answer (score 3):

Your body should tightly control the water concentration (osmolality) via sensors in the brain (osmoreceptors) which send chemical signals (vasopressin) to the kidneys. **These receptors are very sensitive and are capable of making you thirsty with only 1% dehydration.**

So a normal person drinking extra water will just make more urine and pee it out. An abnormal person (elderly, alcoholic or brain/kidney-damaged) may not be able to produce/react to these chemical messages properly.

However the kidneys need to make sure that this extra urine doesn't take salt (predominantly sodium chloride) with it - the salt concentration is also tightly regulated. The urine it makes must therefore be dilute.

If you drink too much water for a prolonged period of time, you wash concentrated salt from the part of the kidney that works to concentrate urine (the renal medulla).

So when you *don't* drink all that extra water, your kidneys are less able to conserve water, you will not be able to make concentrated urine and you will actually become dehydrated (volume deplete).

**Moral of the story: your body knows what it is doing. Drink when you are thirsty.**